# Character Translation using Python (like the tr command)

Tags: python, tr, transliteration

Is there a way to do character translation / transliteration (kind of like the [`tr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr) command) using **Python**?

Some examples in Perl would be:

```perl
my $string = "some fields";
$string =~ tr/dies/eaid/;
print $string;  # domi failed

$string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/a-z/b/d;
print "$string\n";  # b b   b.  (because option "d" is used to delete characters not replaced)
```

Comment: For a Perl guy, calling it translation — as opposed to  transliteration — made finding the right thing to do a bit more complicated.

Comment: For me, the simplest is a [dictionary replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements).

Comment: I've done this [using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

See [`string.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
import string
"abc".translate(string.maketrans("abc", "def")) # => "def"
```

Note the doc's comments about subtleties in the translation of unicode strings.

And for Python 3, you can use directly:

```py
str.translate(str.maketrans("abc", "def"))
```

Edit: Since `tr` is a bit more advanced, also consider using `re.sub`.

Answer (score 28):

If you're using python3 translate is less verbose:

```
>>> 'abc'.translate(str.maketrans('ac','xy'))
'xby'
```

Ahh.. and there is also equivalent to `tr -d`:

```
>>> "abc".translate(str.maketrans('','','b'))
'ac'
```

For `tr -d` with python2.x use an additional argument to translate function:

```
>>> "abc".translate(None, 'b')
'ac'
```

Comment: is there an equivalent for `tr -cd`?

Answer (score 6):

I has developed python-tr, implemented tr algorithm.
Let's try it.

Install:

```
$ pip install python-tr
```

Example:

```
>>> from tr import tr
>>> tr('bn', 'cr', 'bunny')
'curry'
>>> tr('n', '', 'bunny', 'd')
'buy'
>>> tr('n', 'u', 'bunny', 'c')
'uunnu'
>>> tr('n', '', 'bunny', 's')
'buny'
>>> tr('bn', '', 'bunny', 'cd')
'bnn'
>>> tr('bn', 'cr', 'bunny', 'cs')
'brnnr'
>>> tr('bn', 'cr', 'bunny', 'ds')
'uy'
```

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-tr
- https://github.com/ikegami-yukino/python-tr

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `unicode.translate()` accepts ordinary mappings, ie. there's no need to import anything either:

```
>>> u'abc+-'.translate({ord('+'): u'-', ord('-'): u'+', ord('b'): None})
u'ac-+'
```

The `translate()` method is especially useful for swapping characters (as '+' and '-' above), which can't be done with `replace()`, and using `re.sub()` isn't very straightforward for that purpose either.

I have to admit, however, that the repeated use of `ord()` doesn't make the code look like nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

We build a map and then translate letter by letter. When using get for dictionary then the second argument specifying what to return if not find anything.

It could be easily transferred to separate function. Mostly should be very efficient.

```py
def transy(strin, old, new):
  assert len(old)==len(new)
  trans = dict(zip(list(old),list(new)))
  res =  "".join([trans.get(i,i) for i in strin])
  return res

>>> transy("abcd", "abc", "xyz")
'xyzd'
```

Answer (score -5):

A simpler approach may be to use replace. e.g.

```
 "abc".replace("abc", "def")
'def'
```

No need to import anything. Works in Python 2.x

Comment: it works in Python 3 as well but doesn't do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: the  translation `cb` to `wt` should transform `cabbage` to `wattage`