# Adding caption below X-axis for a scatter plot using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I am pretty new to python and to the matplotlib library. I have created a scatter plot using matplotlib and now I wish to add caption a little below the X-axis. This is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

file = open('distribution.txt', 'r')

txt="I need the caption to be present a little below X-axis"

x=[]
y=[]
for line in file:
    new=line.rstrip()
    mystring=new.split("\t")
    x.append(mystring[0])
    y.append(mystring[1])


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.4,0.8,0.5))
ax1.set_title("This is my title")
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax1.scatter(x,y, c='r')
fig.text(.05,.05,txt)
plt.xlim(0, 1.05)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the image my caption is way below the scatter plot, is there a way to bring it exactly below the X-axis? Also my scatter plot looks rectangular, is there a way to make it square like?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as @Nicky V mentioned.

```
plt.xlabel('''Butterfly contract traded

Note: c1-c2-c3 indicates the position: long 2 times c2 and short c1 anc c3''')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 53):

You can simply use `figtext`. You can also change the value of x and y-axes as you want.

```
txt="I need the caption to be present a little below X-axis"
plt.figtext(0.5, 0.01, txt, wrap=True, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=12)
```

Comment: It works but is less object-oriented than [fig.text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.text). +1

Answer (score 34):

Something like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

txt="I need the caption to be present a little below X-axis"

# make some synthetic data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 512)
y = np.random.rand(512)*2.3 + .1

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7))

ax1.set_title("This is my title")
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

# make the edge colors match the facecolors
ax1.scatter(x,y, c='r', edgecolors='face')
# center text
fig.text(.5, .05, txt, ha='center')

# use OO interface    
ax1.set_xlim([0, 1.05])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 2.5])

# resize the figure to match the aspect ratio of the Axes    
fig.set_size_inches(7, 8, forward=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: example result]

might work.  Making this easier to do is on the radar for mpl upstream, but we are still looking for someone to do it.

Comment: 5 years later, it seems there is no better solution. +1. Note the y pos value can be negative to increase the space between the x label and the figure legend.

Comment: We just merged (as in 2 days ago) a PR to put functionality similar to this in main-line Matplotlib.  Should be available in mpl3.4 (Jan21) https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17524

Answer (score 19):

First, I feel weird posting an answer against the co-lead developer of matplotlib.  Obviously, @tacaswell knows matplotlib far better than I ever will.  But at the same time, his answer wasn't dynamic enough for me.  I needed a caption that would always be based on the position of the `xlabel`, and couldn't just use text annotations.

I considered simply changing the `xlabel` to add a newline and the caption text, but that wouldn't clearly differentiate the caption, and you can't do things like change the text size or make it italic in the middle of a text string.

I solved this by using matplotlib's TeX capabilities.  Here's my solution:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

rc('text', usetex=True)

file = open('distribution.txt', 'r')

txt="I need the caption to be present a little below X-axis"

x=[]
y=[]
for line in file:
    new=line.rstrip()
    mystring=new.split("\t")
    x.append(mystring[0])
    y.append(mystring[1])


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.4,0.8,0.5))
ax1.set_title("This is my title")
ax1.set_xlabel(r'\begin{center}X-axis\\*\textit{\small{' + txt + r'}}\end{center}')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax1.scatter(x,y, c='r')
plt.xlim(0, 1.05)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

I did the same thing with the random scatter plot from tacaswell's answer, and here's my result:

[image: Scatter plot with caption]

One warning: if you tweak this to take input string variables, the strings may not be properly escaped for use with TeX.  Escaping LaTeX code is already covered on Stack Overflow, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875504/1404311 .  I used that directly, and then could take arbitrary xlabels and captions.

Comment: This is really nice, but I had to install some extra packages on ubuntu to get it to work (I've never used LaTex before): `sudo apt install texlive texlive-latex-extra cm-super dvipng`.

Comment: To give more context to the word *dynamic*, the significance of this answer is that it attaches the text to the `Axes`, not the `Figure`, and therefore works as you move the plot into figures with different subplot arrangements.  The most common use (for me) is labeling (a) (b), ... in a paper, with the overall figure caption in the latex document.  For more complex graphics, i.e. using `GridSpec` to have subfigures, obviously `fig.text` works for assigning a group of plots to (a), (b), ..., but I use subplots far more than I use gridspecs.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution that I used when I couldn't figure out how to do it in a way that was designed...if that makes sense, was to just add some new lines to the xlabel plt.xlabel("xaxis label\n\n\n\ncaption") This just puts the caption a couple new lines under the x axis which makes it look like a caption even thought it's really part of the xaxis label

Comment: Yeah, after using `figtext`, I also came to know that `\n` in `xlabel` works. Thanks for posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

I found another trick, using `plt.text()` you can set the y position below the plot canvas, and it can work as a caption. You can adjust fontsize, colour and even where the line breaks using \n. I am using this method

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use negative position for the y to extend the figure outside the current size.

```
fig.text(0.5, -0.05, 'some caption', ha='center')
```

The coordinate is of the figure, where 0,0 means the lower left end, and 1,1 corresponds to the top right.

An example -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
plt.scatter(x, y)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.text(0.5, -0.05, 'A scattered plot with caption', ha='center')
```

[image: A scattered plot with caption]