# Matplotlib while debugging in Pycharm: How to turn off interactive mode?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm, python-interactive

First of all, I am working on the Pycharm debug console and want to put a caption under my diagram. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011963/5240546) this can be achieved by:

```
plt.plot([2,5,1,2]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(.5, .05, "text", ha="center")
plt.show()
```

However, this shows me the plot at first, then an empty window (after typing the second line) and nothing later.

I figured out this must be because of interactive mode of matplotlib so I turned it off using `plt.ioff()` in the debug session after which `plt.isinteractive()` returns `False`. Still this does not change its behaviour and shows the plot right after the `plt.plot(...)` command.

Weirdly enough when I put `plt.ioff()` in my script, it is ignored and `plt.isinteractive()` returns `True`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ioff()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
print(plt.isinteractive())
```

My system information:

- PyCharm CE 2017.3.2
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Python 3.6.3 in an Anaconda Environment

Can anyone reproduce this? Is there another way to create more complicated diagrams from the Pycharm debug console? I would prefer to not change my development environment everytime I want to plot something more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question: use a different (non interactive) backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Your code is probably not working because you created the figure instance after your plot. Try:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([2,5,1,2]
fig.text(.5, .05, "text", ha="center")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using your suggested different backend does not show me any plot now. Nether with `plt.plot(...)` nor with `plt.plot(...)` and `plt.show()`. Executing my test file (without `matplotlib.use('Agg')`) from the bash works as expected: it displays the plots after `plt.show()` and I can even do interactive plotting with pdb.

Comment: That is what a non interactive backend does, it is not supposed to open a window with your plot in it. Where you able to solve your original problem with the text not showing by switching the figure and plot call?

Comment: The text works now, thanks! But my main problem that I want to plot in debug mode of pycharm just like it works from the bash with pdb is not solved.

Comment: It still displays empty figures?

Comment: It still either displays the plot directly when executing `plt.plot(...)` or nothing when I switch to a non-interactive backend like you described. I would like to have the plot displayed when I run `plt.show()` like it works on the bash with pdf.

Comment: Could you add `import matplotlib` followed by `print(matplotlib.rcParams['backend'])` at the top of your script (before other imports) and report what it does when a) executed from bash b) executed using pycharm

Comment: They both return `MacOSX`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166941/discussion-between-peterheuz-and-flyingteller).

Comment: What is 'Agg' please?

Comment: @slashdottir It"s the backend that uses the `Anti-Grain Geometry engine`. For more info on backends, [read the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend)