# Text below a figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I managed to add text on the figure with

```py
        fg_ax.text(
            0.05,
            0.1,
            f"n = {len(df)}",
        )
```

`fg_ax` being my `matplotlib.axes` object

But I want it below the figure. Because my y coordinates go from 0 to 1, I figured after reading the documentation that doing something like this would put it below:

```py
        fg_ax.text(
            0.05,
            -0.5,
            f"n = {len(df)}",
        )
```

But there is nothing that appears anymore, as if I was writing "outside" what is displayed.

I tried `plt.show()` and `fg_ax.figure.savefig`. None works.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = (30 * np.random.rand(N)) ** 2  # 0 to 15 point radii

_, fg_ax = plt.subplots()
fg_ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
fg_ax.text(
    0.05,
    -0.5,
    f"n = qsdfqsdf",
)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I run the code in your MRE with no modifications a figure is generated that shows the text "n = qsdfqsdf" below the axes/plot area. Maybe something is cropping your figure display area?

Comment: This is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/5cFHr9v.png

Comment: I'm using PyCharm, maybe you are using another IDE?

Comment: I'm using the IDE Spyder 5.3.1. The plot is rendering in-line in a pane of the IDE window: https://imgur.com/a/EIp8crv

Comment: That's exactly what I would want @DoodleVib. Do you know how to save this on a .pdf or a .png so that this works (with `fg_ax.figure.savefig`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010205/adding-caption-below-x-axis-for-a-scatter-plot-using-matplotlib), I've changed your code to the following:

```py
N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = (30 * np.random.rand(N)) ** 2  # 0 to 15 point radii

fig, fg_ax = plt.subplots()
fg_ax.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.figtext(
    0.2, 0.01, f"n = qsdfqsdf", wrap=True, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=10
)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
plt.savefig("image.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Although it works, I cannot make the text go "more down" than `y = 0.0`.

Comment: I've edited my answer: is this better? Now, you can also save the image as a pdf.

Comment: `verticalalignment='top'` will let text overflow below `y=0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using `verticalalignment='top'` to put text below the existing figure, effectively extending the figure downwards:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = "{\n  Metadata,\n  Unknown,\n  Amount,\n}"

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(3,3))

fig.text(0, 0, text, va='top')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

Which gives:

[image]