# Javascript fat arrow functions vs Python lambda functions

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, lambda

I am implementing a Javascript class in Python 3, and I would like to verify if my code is correct, and how I could refactor it further.

This is the Javascript code:

```
class DbResult {
    constructor(data) {
        let self = this;
        data = data || {};
        self.status = data.status || 'info';
        self.message = data.message || null;

    }

    static map(row) {
        let dbResult = new DbResult();

        if(!row) { return dbResult; }

        for(let property in row) {
            if(row.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                const name = property.replace(/_[a-zA-Z]/g, (match) => {
                    return match[1].toUpperCase();
            });
            dbResult[name] = row[property];
        }
    }
    return dbResult;
}
module.exports = DbResult;
```

This is my Python implementation. I'm not certain if I used the lambda expression correctly.

```
import re

class DbResult:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        if data.status is None:
            self.status = 'info'
        else:
            self.status = data.status
        if data.message is not None:
            self.message = data.message

    @staticmethod
    def map(row):
        dbResult = DbResult()

        if row is None:
            return dbResult

        for prop in row:
            if row.has_key(prop):
                name = re.sub("_[a-zA-Z]", lambda match: match[1].upper(), prop)
            dbResult[name] = row[name]

        return dbResult
```

Comment: did you test that your code is correctly running or not ?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki This class is part of a full-scale app. I have yet to finish the unit test cases before I can verify.

Comment: You can find an answer for your lambda function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python . You have to use `match.group()` instead of `match[1]`.

Comment: Unless you're doing something exotic, you can simply do `prop.upper()` instead of that regexp.

Comment: @JulCh, so `lambda match: match.group().upper()`?

Comment: @Bargain23, yes, `.group()` will return the string matched by the regex.