# How can I replace each letter in the sentence to sentence without breaking it?

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my problem.

```
    sentence = "This car is awsome."
```

and what I want do do is

```
    sentence.replace("a","<emoji:a>")
    sentence.replace("b","<emoji:b>")
    sentence.replace("c","<emoji:c>")
```

and so on...

But of course if I do it in that way the letters in `"<emoji:>"` will also be replaced as I go along. So how can I do it in other way?

Comment: Assign it back: `sentence = sentence.replace("a","<emoji:a>")`

Comment: That's not the point, I need to replace all letters to words, without messing with already replaced ones.

Comment: I was not answering you, but explaining what you should do when you do `replace`.

Comment: create a dictionary that maps letter to command (e.g) dict = {"a";"<emoji:a>"}
then just go through the sentence serially replace each letter by the correct emoji and join it back at the end

Comment: Awsome, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

As Carlos Gonzalez suggested:

create a mapping dict and apply it to each character in sequence:

```
sentence = "This car is awsome."

# mapping
up = {"a":"<emoji:a>",
      "b":"<emoji:b>",
      "c":"<emoji:c>",}

# apply mapping to create a new text (use up[k] if present else default to k)
text = ''.join( (up.get(k,k) for k in sentence) )

print(text)
```

Output:

```
This <emoji:c><emoji:a>r is <emoji:a>wsome.
```

The advantage of the generator expression inside the `''.join( ... generator ...)` is that it takes each single character of `sentence` and either keeps it or replaces it. It only ever touches each char once, so there is no danger of multiple substitutions and it takes only one pass of `sentence` to convert the whole thing.

Doku: [dict.get(key,default)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

---

If you used

```
sentence = sentence.replace("a","o")
sentence = sentence.replace("o","k")
```

you would first make `o` from `a` and then make `k` from any `o` (or `a` before) - and you would have to touch each character twice to make it happen.

Using

```
up = { "a":"o", "o":"k" }
text = ''.join( (up.get(k,k) for k in sentence) )
```

avoids this.

Comment: You can easily fool this code by adding `"e":"<emoji:e>"` to `up`... I think that's the main point of the question to begin with.

Comment: @norok2 did you try it out? You could fool it if you replaced one after another - but the list comp doesn't. It works on every single character of `sentence` and creates an itermediary generator that either keeps the character or replaces it. the generator is then stick together again. nothing gets processed multiple times. - if you appended to `up` as suggested, the `text` would be `This <emoji:c><emoji:a>r is <emoji:a>wsom<emoji:e>`

Comment: You are right. I read it too quickly. But the this trick would not work for multi-char replacements, right?

Comment: @norok2 if you want to replace more then 1 char it is easier to do this using regex and sub - see [passing a function to re.sub in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python) - but thats needs the `re` module as import and is not needed in this case - see the 2nd answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace more then 1 character at a time, it would be easier to do this with regex. Inspired by [Passing a function to re.sub in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python)

```
import re 

sentence = "This car is awsome."

up = {"is":"Yippi",
      "ws":"WhatNot",}

# modified it to create the groups using the dicts key
text2 = re.sub( "("+'|'.join(up)+")", lambda x: up[x.group()], sentence)

print(text2)
```

Output:

```
ThYippi car Yippi aWhatNotome.
```

Doku: [re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

You would have to take extra care with your keys, if you wanted to use "regex" specific characters that have another meaning if used as regex-pattern - f.e. `.+*?()[]^$`