# Replace Unicode code point with actual character using regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode, emoji, python-re

I have a large file where any unicode character that wasn't in UTF-8 got replaced by its code point in angle brackets (e.g. the "" was converted to "<U+0001F44D>"). Now I want to revert this with a regex substitution.

I've tried to acomplish this with

`re.sub(r'<U\+([A-F0-9]+)>',r'\U\1', str)`

but obviously this won't work because we cannot insert the group into this unicode escape.
What's the best/easiest way to do this? I found many questions trying to do the exact opposite but nothing useful to 're-encode' these code points as actual characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a number of the character, you can do `ord(number)` to get the character of that number.

Because we have a string, we need to read it as int with base 16.

Both of those together:

```py
>>> chr(int("0001F44D", 16))
''
```

However, now we have a small function, not a string to simply replace! [Quick search returned that you can pass a function to re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python)

Now we get:

```py
re.sub(r'<U\+([A-F0-9]+)>', lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1), 16)), my_str)
```

PS Don't name your string just `str` - you'll shadow the builtin str meaning type.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that there is any possibility to use a function with `re.sub`! I was thinking of using the chr() function here, but didn't know how to use it with the regex substitution. The `str` was only for debugging purposes, I will use this with a dataset mapping function! Thanks a lot!