# pass regex group to function for substituting

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group, python-re, regexp-replace

I have a passage of text that contains VALID dates formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. I need to replace all months to their respective month name.

10/05/1999 -> 10 May 1999

I find dates and capture each part in its own group with
`'([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})'`

I need to pass group 2 to a function/dictionary that returns month name. Unsure of how to do that.

```py
def test(s):
    print(s)
    return f">> {s} <<"

rep = re.sub('([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})', '\g<1> '+test('\g<2>')+' \g<3>', '10/05/1999')
#execution of test prints below
#'\g<2>'

print(rep)
#10 >> 05 << 1999
```

As you can see the literal string `'\g<2>'` is passed to test() function rather than the group content itself, which is `'05'`. As a result I cannot perform month number to month name conversion. What can be done instead?

Comment: Did you try using a lambda? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737863/passing-a-function-to-re-sub-in-python

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you, just tried the same but now '\g<1>' and '\g<3>' are taken as literal string rather than captured group, ie my output is now ``\g<1> May \g<2>``. Can you provide an example maybe?

Comment: If you look at the linked page, you see that you have to use `lambda x:` and then use `x.group(1)` for example.

Comment: `rep = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: f'{x.group(1)} {test(x.group(2))} {x.group(3)}', '10/05/1999')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it, thank you both