# How to replace one umlaut and the following character with two other characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace German Umlauts (*Ä*, *ä*, *Ö*, *ö*, *Ü*, *ü*, *ß*) with their two-letter equivalents (*Ae*, *ae*, *Oe*, *oe*, *Ue*, *ue*, *ss*).

Currently, I have this function, but the string's length changes:

```
def _translate_umlauts(s):
    """Translate a string into ASCII.

    This Umlaut translation comes from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2400577/152439
    """
    trans = {"\xe4" : "ae"}   # and more ...
    patt = re.compile("|".join(trans.keys()))
    return patt.sub(lambda x: trans[x.group()], s)
```

However, I have the requirement that the string's total length should not change. For example, *Mär* should become *Mae*.

Any help in deriving the appropriate solution (regex?) is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, you can regex-match `Ä.` and replace it with `Ae`... but that won't work if the last character is `Ä`, and indiscriminately eating the following character is a pretty odd thing to do, isn't it?

Comment: The string length should not change? What a stupid requirement is this?

Comment: This is odd. After doing the replacement, how do you tell the difference between "löten" and "lösen" which both result in "loeen" ?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the string's total length should not change.

Well, that's an odd requirement, but

```
patt = re.compile("([" + "".join(trans.keys()) + "]).")
```

Note that this will not replace the umlaut if it is the last character in the string. For obvious reasons this would change the string length.

Answer (score 1):

Just truncate back to the original string length:

```
return patt.sub(lambda x: trans[x.group()], s)[:len(s)]
```