# String replace - avoid repeat

Tags: python, string

I am working on merging a few datasets regarding over 200 countries in the world. In cleaning the data I need to convert some three-letter codes for each country into the countries' full names.

The three-letter codes and country full names come from a separate CSV file, which shows a slightly different set of countries.

My question is: Is there a better way to write this?

```
str.replace("USA", "United States of America")
str.replace("CAN", "Canada")
str.replace("BHM", "Bahamas")
str.replace("CUB", "Cuba")
str.replace("HAI", "Haiti")
str.replace("DOM", "Dominican Republic")
str.replace("JAM", "Jamaica")
```

and so on. It goes on for another 200 rows. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to replace a string using a dictionary of replacements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, don't you need to check word boundaries? "USAIN BOLT" will be replaced to "United States of AmericaIN BOLT".

Comment: @AkiRoss Just word boundaries? What about "The USA."?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by that: are you questioning the semantic value of word boundary or its syntactic form? (Or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of substitution is high, I would instead iterate over the words in the string and replace based upon a dictionary lookup.

```
mapofcodes = {'USA': 'United States of America', ....}
for word in mystring.split():
    finalstr += mapofcodes.get(word, word)
```

Comment: Did you mean `mystring.split()`? Wouldn't a loop over `mystring` just iterate over the chars?

Comment: Yes. I meant mystring.split(). Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the CSV file into a dictionary to a 2D array, you can access which ever one you want then.

that is if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular expressions solution:

```
import re

COUNTRIES = {'USA': 'United States of America', 'CAN': 'Canada'}

def repl(m):
    country_code = m.group(1)
    return COUNTRIES.get(country_code, country_code)

p = re.compile(r'([A-Z]{3})')
my_string = p.sub(repl, my_string)
```