# Replace words by checking from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below.

```
ID  Word       Synonyms
------------------------
1   drove      drive
2   office     downtown
3   everyday   daily
4   day        daily
5   work       downtown
```

I'm reading a sentence and would like to replace words in that sentence with their synonyms as defined above. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import string

sdf = pd.read_excel('C:\synonyms.xlsx')
sd = sdf.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
words = 'i drove to office everyday in my car'

#######

def tokenize(text):
    text = ''.join([ch for ch in text if ch not in string.punctuation])
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    synonym = synonyms(tokens)
    return synonym

def synonyms(words):
    for word in words:
        if(sd[sd['Word'] == word].index.tolist()):
            idx = sd[sd['Word'] == word].index.tolist()
            word = sd.loc[idx]['Synonyms'].item()
        else:
            word
    return word

print(tokenize(words))
```

The code above tokenizes the input sentence. I would like to achieve the following output:

**In**: `i drove to office everyday in my car`
**Out**: `i drive to downtown daily in my car`

But the output I get is

**Out**: `car`

If I skip the `synonyms` function, then my output has no issues and is split into individual words. I am trying to understand what I'm doing wrong in the `synonyms` function. Also, please advise if there is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: at the end of your `synonyms` method you only `return word` - thus its returned value is the final `word in words`

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements

Comment: thanks, but there is no usage of a dataframe for dictionary

Comment: What's the nature of your synonym mapping? Is it one-to-one? many-to-one? one-to-many?

Comment: many-to-one , i have updated my example dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of Pandas/NumPy indexing. Since your synonym mapping is many-to-one, you can re-index using the `Word` column.

```
sd = sd.applymap(str.strip).applymap(str.lower).set_index('Word').Synonyms
print(sd)
```

```
Word
drove          drive
office      downtown
everyday       daily
day            daily
Name: Synonyms, dtype: object
```

Then, you can easily align a list of tokens to their respective synonyms.

```
words = nltk.word_tokenize(u'i drove to office everyday in my car')
sentence = sd[words].reset_index()
print(sentence)
```

```
       Word  Synonyms
0         i       NaN
1     drove     drive
2        to       NaN
3    office  downtown
4  everyday     daily
5        in       NaN
6        my       NaN
7       car       NaN
```

Now, it remains to use the tokens from `Synonyms`, falling back to `Word`. This can be achieved with

```
sentence = sentence.Synonyms.fillna(sentence.Word)
print(sentence.values)
```

```
[u'i' 'drive' u'to' 'downtown' 'daily' u'in' u'my' u'car']
```

Comment: this seems to have issue if i have many to one mapping , I have updated my synonym table in the question and my input as "i drove to office everyday in my car to work" the last word "work" is not replaced

Comment: @Rohit are you sure? I just checked, it works for me.

Comment: yea , here is my print
Word
drove          drive
office      downtown
everyday       daily
rattle           rat
rattles          rat
mold         molding
bumps           bump
bumpy           bump
work        downtown
---------
       Word  Synonyms
0         i       NaN
1     drove     drive
2        to       NaN
3    office  downtown
4  everyday     daily
5        in       NaN
6        my       NaN
7       car       NaN
8        to       NaN
9      work       NaN
['i' 'drive' 'to' 'downtown' 'daily' 'in' 'my' 'car' 'to' 'work']

Comment: here is output i see : ['i' 'drive' 'to' 'downtown' 'daily' 'in' 'my' 'car' 'to' 'work']

Comment: What's your version of Pandas/Python? also, please post a full, runnable example on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), the output in your comment is illegible.

Comment: The problem could lie in the way you are loading your synonyms. I am creating the data frame inline using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133923/discussion-between-rohit-gopidi-and-igor-raush).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
sdf = pd.read_excel('C:\synonyms.xlsx')
rep = dict(zip(sdf.Word, sdf.Synonyms)) #convert into dictionary

words = "i drove to office everyday in my car"
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
rep = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], words)

print rep
```

output

```
i drive to downtown daily in my car
```

Courtesy : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117124/6626530