# Replace a string using dictionary - regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of slangs with their meanings and I want to replace all the slangs in my text.

I have found partially working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400577

For now my code looks like this:

```
import re

myText = 'brb some sample text I lov u. I need some $$ for 2mw.'

dictionary = {
  'brb': 'be right back',
  'lov u': 'love you',
  '$$': 'money',
  '2mw': 'tomorrow'
}

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in dictionary.keys()) + r')\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dictionary[x.group()], myText)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
be right back some sample text I love you. I need some $$ for tomorrow.
```

As you can see sings $$ haven't changed and I know it is due to `\b` syntax. How can I change my regex to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the word boundaries with lookarounds that check for any word chars around the search phrase

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in dictionary.keys()) + r')(?!\w)')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NE7V3C)

The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the current location and the `(?!\w)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Replace `(?<!\w)` with `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\w)` with `(?!\S)` if you need to only match search phrases in between whitespace chars and start/end of string.