# 'Key Error' in Case Insensitive Regex Dictionary String Replace

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, case-insensitive

With reference to both of these links:

- [Case insensitive dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082152/case-insensitive-dictionary),
- [Replace a string using dictionary - regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102201/replace-a-string-using-dictionary-regex)

I am trying to use this method to be able to replace from a user inputted string using a dictionary created from a CSV but with case insensitivity.

The solution in question is as follows:

```
string=input("Please enter your string")
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in sorted(dict.keys(),key=len, reverse=True)) + r')(?!\w)')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dict[x.group()], string)
print(result)
```

now I've tried using the `RE.IGNORECASE` method on the end of my compile, as well as using the "Case Insensitive Dictionary Method" to change my initial dictionary but no matter each method I try I keep getting the same error whenever the input isn't an exact match for the keywords `"Key Error 'keyword' doesn't match"`.

Comment: Please post the whole reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your dictionary keys only have lower case words or only uppercase words, you could do something like this:

```
import re
dict = {'KEYWORD': "replacement_keyword", 'EXAMPLE': 'b', 'EXAMPLE2: 2': 'c'}
string=input("Please enter your string")
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in sorted(dict.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)) + r')(?!\w)', re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dict[str.upper(x.group())], string)
print(result)
```

By using **str.upper** or **str.lower** in case your keys are lower cases, you match your keys.

The Output yields:

```
Please enter your string: Keyword KEYWORD keyWord
replacement_keyword replacement_keyword replacement_keyword
```

I hope this solves, what you want to achieve, otherwise please provide more context.