# How to change certain letters in a word list (words contain in text file) with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a word list contains in a text file; below I show an example:

```
place
lime
nest
land
```

I want to get an other file with the content below:

```
pl@ce
lim3
n3st
l@nd
```

This mean that:

- the letter `a` must be transform in in the char `@` but in a word must be only 1 change so `apart` becomes `ap@rt` and not `@p@rt`.
- the letter `e` must be transform in in the number `3`

This is first time that I use stackoverflow so sorry for my writing and for my English.

I'm also new to coding (python) so I might not understand all the code very well.

Comment: if you have the letter that you want to replace 2 times in a word which one should be replaced, the first or the second or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

Split input string into individual words, replace first instance of 'a' with '@' in each word. Append edited words to output string.

```
input = 'place lime nest land'
output = ''

input = input.split(' ')

for i in input:
    i = i.replace('a', '@', 1)
    i = i.replace('e', '3', 1)
    output += i + ' '

print(output)
```

Output:

```
@part pl@c3 lim3 n3st l@nd
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions you can do

```
import re
s1 = re.sub(r'a(?=[^a]*?\b)', '@', 'apart place lime nest land')
s2 = re.sub(r'e(?=[^e]*?\b)', '3', s1)
print(s2)
```

Using the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102201/replace-a-string-using-dictionary-regex) question. We can combine it into a single expression:

```
subs = {'a': '@', 'e': '3'}
pattern = re.compile(r'a(?=[^a]*?\b)|e(?=[^e]*?\b)')
s = pattern.sub(lambda x: subs[x.group()], 'apart place lime nest land')

print(s)
```

Output:

```
ap@rt pl@c3 lim3 n3st l@nd
```

This replaces the last letter `a` and last letter `e` within a word.

Answer (score 0):

### Input from file, output to file

This code read words from the file `file1.txt` and write the changed word on `file2.txt`:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    with open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for word in f:
            word = word.replace("a", "@", 1)
            word = word.replace("e", "3", 1)
            f2.write(word)
```

This change only the first occurrance of a letter, so `apart` becomes `@part`.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the string, replace first occurence, then reverse the string back. (Hardcoded)

```
print('apart place lime nest land'[::-1].replace('a', '@', 3).replace('e', '3',2)[::-1])
# ap@rt pl@ce lim3 n3st l@nd
```

Answer (score -2):

this may be a rough first draft and some assumptions were made but here is a shot at a function.  Could be cleaned up alot.  Good luck

```
def updt_text(s):
    # assumptions, string of text is seperated by spaces and there are no odd characters
    words = s.split()
    newwords = []
    
    dictChanges = {
        'a': '@',
        'e': '3',
    }
    
    for word in words:
        for k, v in dictChanges.items():
            if k in word:
                word = word.replace(k, v)
                break
        newwords.append(word)
    
    return newwords
```

Comment: why is this a minus 2, thanks, still learning to submit helpful answers and learn, :)