# Printing a message with an emoji

Tags: python

I'm trying to print `:)` as an emoji.

When I input "Hi :)", it should print "Hi ", but instead I'm getting my original input.

How can I solve it?

My code so far:

```py
messages = input("> ")

emoji = {
    ":)" : "'",
    ":(" : "'",
    "-_-" : ""
}

output = " "
for message in messages:
    emoji.get(message)
    output += emoji.get(message, message)
print(output)
```

Comment: Few tips - 1. I don't know how you read input and where you write output, but you should have trouble with unicode characters (like emojis) if you use a console. Try working with a file, for instance `python my_program < input.txt > output,.txt`.

Comment: 2. Carefully read your usage of `dict.get()`, you might want to use `for message in messages.split(' ')` instead, because `input()` will always return one result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make multiple replacements in a string using a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/how-can-i-make-multiple-replacements-in-a-string-using-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```py
messages = input("> ")

emoji = {
    ":)" : "'",
    ":(" : "'",
    "-_-" : ""
}

mess = messages.result()
for key in emoji.keys():
    if key in mess:
        mess = mess.replace(key, emoji[key])
print(mess)
```

my input:

> :) and :( and -_-
> my result:

```py
 and  and
```

in jupyterLite input asked for result, but in my python I could do something similar.

```py
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    emoji = {
        ":\)|=\)": "",
        ":\(|=\(": "",
        "-_-": ""
    }

    mess = input('> ')

    for key, value in emoji.items():
        pattern = key  # Escape special characters in the key
        match = re.search(pattern, mess)
        
        if match:
            print(f"found pattern = {key}")
            mess = re.sub(pattern, value, mess)  # Replace the key with the corresponding emoji
    print(mess)
```

ps> as stated by nigh-anxiety looping the input array is not the aproach.

Loop the keys of emoji instead.

Comment: You beat me to posting basically the same code solution.  You should add some explanation as to what the issue with the original posters code was (the `for message in messages` part) and why this solution works instead of that.

Comment: True, his code had logic mistake.

Answer (score -1):

```
import emoji 


print(emoji.emojize(":grinning_face_with_big_eyes:")) 
print(emoji.emojize(":winking_face_with_tongue:")) 
print(emoji.emojize(":zipper-mouth_face:"))
```

More details : [Python program to print Emojis](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-emojis/)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in your `for message in messages:` loop, `message` is always a single character, so it will never match any of the keys in your emoji dictionary.

There are multiple possible solutions for this.  Here's a basic solution using str.replace(), where we loop over the emojis in the dictionary, find each one in the message, and replace it:

```
    messages = input("> ")

    emojis = {
    ":)" : "'",
    ":(" : "'",
    "-_-" : ""
    }

    for key, emoji in emojis.items():
        if key in messages:
            messages = messages.replace(key, emoji)
        
    print(messages)
```

Sample output:

```
> Hello :)  :(  _-_-_-_-_
Hello '  '  ___
```

Comment: Looks like Hildermes had the same ideas as me and beat me to the punch, although he should add more explanation as to WHY that solution works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code for your purpose:

```
messages = input("> ")

emoji = {
    ":)" : "",
    ":(" : "",
    "-_-" : ""
}

output = " "
for word in messages.split(" "):
    if word in emoji.keys():
        messages = messages.replace(word,emoji.get(word.strip()))
        
    output = messages
    
print(output)
```

In the above code, we first get all the words in the input. If a word in the input is a key of the emoji dictionary, then we replace that word(or symbol) with the corresponding emoji from the dictionary. Finally, we print the modified input. This will work even if any number of emojis are entered.

Output:

```
>:) and :( and -_-
 and  and 

> :) and -_- and :( and :)
 and  and  and
```

Answer (score -2):

Make your dictionary like this:

```
emoji = {
    ")" : "'",
    "(" : "'",
    "_" : ""
}
```

Your code then should work successfully.

Comment: It would help if you explained how this fixes the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really should have explained

Comment: @abdelrahman, you still can. Just [edit] your answer.