# Replace string from dict values

Tags: python

I have this function for replacing substrings according to a dict:

```py
def unescape(val):
    escaped_dict = {'7D5D':'7D', '7D33':'13', '7D31':'11', '7D5E':'7E'}
    res = val
    for key, value in escaped_dict.items():
        res = res.replace(key, value)
    return res

print(unescape("A20327D5D5D7D5D33"))
>>
A20327D5D13
```

ok changed 7D5D to 7D, but after it changed 7D33 to 13. I want to replace only once (eg: A20327D5D5D7D33).

The solution would be to add:

```py
if key in val:
    return res
```

But when there are several or more values from the dict to exchange it won't work.

Comment: Is there a formulas to get replacement from pattern?

Comment: Replace takes an additional argument `maxreplace`. So `res = res.replace(key, value, 1)` should replace just once.

Comment: If you only want to replace once, use the optional third argument to `replace`: `res = val.replace(key, value, 1)` and return `res` if `res != val`.

Comment: Using [re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400504/easiest-way-to-replace-a-string-using-a-dictionary-of-replacements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble in your, is that when you change `7D5D33` to `7D33` in the first iteration, teh result will be changed to `13` in the next iteration because `7D33` is in `escaped_dict.keys`.

You can for example, change the patterns into not used characters:

```
def unescape(val):
    escaped_dict = {'7D5D':'__7D__', '7D33':'__13__', '7D31':'__11__', '7D5E':'__7E__'}
    escaped_dict2 = {'__7D__':'7D', '__13__':'13', '__11__': '11', '__7E__': '7E'}
    res = val
    for key, value in escaped_dict.items():
        res = res.replace(key, value)

    # This part could be replaced by the code the update section.
    for key, value in escaped_dict2.items():
        res = res.replace(key, value)
    
    return res
```

But, I recommand to use `re.sub`, this is very appropriate here.

### Update: `re.sub` solution

To do the second replacement:

```
import re
res = re.sub(r"__([\dA-Z]{2})__", r"\1", res)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example using re.sub?

Comment: Thanks, which solution will be optimal from the point of view of load with a large number of runs?

Comment: The second one because there is no loop.

Comment: im using micropython, and then replace with re solution give result this: __7E__A2032__7D__5D__7D__33 ?

Comment: really? what is micropython?

Comment: python3 for microcontrollers :)

Comment: Ok. May be re module is not installed by default

Comment: is installed, doc: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/ure.html