# Regex Replace Python

Tags: python, string

In my project I need to be able to replace a regex in a string to another.

For example if I have 2 regular expressions `[a-c]` and `[x-z]`, I need to be able to replace the string "abc" with "xyz", or the string "hello adan" with "hello xdxn". How would I do this?

Comment: You want to replace the regex in the string, or you want to *use* the regex to replace a substring in the string? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @xdhmoore I added a second example.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want to do something like `tr`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555705/character-translation-using-python-like-the-tr-command

Comment: Yes I believe that does @xdhmoore Thank you!

Comment: This is what I propose although I use only base python functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We build a map and then translate letter by letter.
When using get for dictionary then the second argument specifying what to return if not find.

```py
>>> trans = dict(zip(list("xyz"),list("abc")))
>>> trans
{'x': 'a', 'y': 'b', 'z': 'c'}
>>> "".join([trans.get(i,i) for i in "hello xdxn"])
'hello adan'
>>>
```

Or change the order in trans to go in other direction

```py
>>> trans = dict(zip(list("abc"),list("xyz")))
>>> trans
{'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}
>>> "".join([trans.get(i,i) for i in "hello adan"])
'hello xdxn'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>>replace = re.sub(r'[a-c]+', 'x','Hello adan')
>>>replace
'Hello xdxn'
>>>re.sub(r'[a-c]+', 'x','Hello bob')
'Hello xox'
```