# How to replace all T with U in an input string of DNA?

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

So, the task is quite simple. I just need to replace all "T"s with "U"s in an input string of DNA. I have written the following code:

```
def transcribe_dna_to_rna(s):
base_change = {"t":"U", "T":"U"}
replace = "".join([base_change(n,n) for n in s])
return replace.upper()
```

and for some reason, I get the following error code:

```
'dict' object is not callable
```

Why is it that my dictionary is not callable? What should I change in my code?
Thanks for any tips in advance!

Comment: Note that in bioinformatics, case (lower or upper) is often important and should be preserved, so keeping both t ->u and T -> U is important. See, for example, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/225/6251

Answer (score 3):

To correctly convert DNA to RNA nucleotides in string `s`, use a combination of [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), which replaces thymine to uracil while preserving the case. For example:

```
s = 'ACTGactgACTG'
s = s.translate(str.maketrans("tT", "uU"))
print(s)
# ACUGacugACUG
```

Note that in bioinformatics, case (lower or upper) is often important and should be preserved, so keeping both `t -> u` and `T -> U` is important. See, for example:
[Uppercase vs lowercase letters in reference genome](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/225/6251)

**SEE ALSO:**
[Character Translation using Python (like the tr command)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/555705/967621)

Note that there are specialized bioinformatics tools specifically for handling biological sequences.

For example, [BioPython](https://biopython.org/) offers [`transcribe`](https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq):

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq = Seq('ACTGactgACTG')
my_seq = my_seq.transcribe()
print(my_seq)
# ACUGacugACUG
```

To install BioPython, use `conda install biopython` or `conda create --name biopython biopython`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error tells you that `base_change(n,n)` looks like you are trying to use `base_change` as the name of a function, when in fact it is a dictionary.

I guess what you wanted to say was

```py
def transcribe_dna_to_rna(s):
    base_change = {"t":"U", "T":"U"}
    replace = "".join([base_change.get(n, n) for n in s])
    return replace.upper()
```

where the function is the `.get(x, y)` method of the dictionary, which returns the value for the key in `x` if it is present, and otherwise `y` (so in this case, return the original `n` if it's not in the dictionary).

But this is overcomplicating things; Python very easily lets you replace characters in strings.

```py
def transcribe_dna_to_rna(s):
    return s.upper().replace("T", "U")
```

(Stole the reordering to put the `.upper()` first from @norie's answer; thanks!)

If your real dictionary was much larger, your original attempt might make more sense, as long chains of `.replace().replace().replace()...` are unattractive and eventually inefficient when you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translation#str.translate):

```
dna = "ACTG"
rna = dna.translate(str.maketrans("T", "U"))  # "ACUG"
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `s` to upper and then do the replacement.

```py
def transcribe_dna_to_rna(s):
    return s.upper().replace("T", "U")
```