# replace value in one column without using replace() function

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I want to replace string without using `replace()` function.
Only want to use `pandas` and `numpy`.

sample data:

```
# df
Col1
ab1
de4
```

The logic of replace is:

1. `a` will be `i`
2. `b` will be `g`
3. `d` will be `m`
4. `e` will be `t`
5. `1` will be `2`
6. `4` will be `3`

Is there any way that I can create a dictionary and use this to identify and replace?

```
# df
Col1   Col2
ab1    ig2
de4    mt3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character Translation using Python (like the tr command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555705/character-translation-using-python-like-the-tr-command)

Comment: but this need `string` package. If I only want to use `pandas` and `numpy`, how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `translate`.

```py
mapping = 'abde14'.maketrans({
    'a': 'i',
    'b': 'g',
    'd': 'm',
    'e': 't',
    '1': '2',
    '4': '3'
})

df['Col2'] = df.Col1.str.translate(mapping)
```

If it is always mapping to 1 character, this syntax might be more compact.

```py
mapping = str.maketrans('abde14', 'igmt23')
```

Comment: Does 'abde14' be the required string before `maketrans()`?

Comment: oh, seems not necessary.  But this was using it, I don't know the difference, though. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-translate/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your function for it and use apply.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = ['asdsd', 'xxx', '41xwqa']

def custom_replace(element):
    translate_dict = {
        'a': 'i',
        'b': 'g',
        'd': 'm',
        'e': 't',
        '1': '2',
        '4': '3'
    }
    return_element = ''
    for char in element:
        try:
            return_element += translate_dict[char]
        except:
            return_element += char
    return return_element

df['col'].apply(custom_replace)
```