# Bulk remove character from string

Tags: python

I’m trying to optimize my code.  I have a list of strings that have quite a few characters I don’t want.  Rather than just call

```
My_string.replace(‘!’, ‘’).replace(‘$’, ‘’)…
```

I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  I have probably 50-60 characters that need to be removed.  I do need to use pairs somehow because not every character is being replaced with nothing.

Comment: Please pay extremely close attention to the types of quotes you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character Translation using Python (like the tr command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555705/character-translation-using-python-like-the-tr-command) If you're simply removing them instead of substituting, consider a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

first of all those quotes are misleading, so I'll use the standard ones. You can create a translation table using the `str.maketrans` method and then use `str.translate`.

something like this:

```py
# Define a dictionary with characters to be replaced as keys and their replacements as values 
# ('char to substitute': 'substitution')

replace_chars = {
    '!': '',
    '$': 's',
    # Add more characters and replacements here
}

# Create a translation table
translation_table = str.maketrans(replace_chars)

my_string = "Your input $tring!"

# Use translate to remove/replace characters
cleaned_string = my_string.translate(translation_table)
```